# Position RadialGradient center in an absolute position (in pixels) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I'm trying to position the center of a RadialGradient in a specific position expressed in pixels (i.e. x pixels from the left and y pixels from the top). However, the "center" parameter of RadialGradient expects a widget of type AlignmentGeometry, and I don't know any widget of that type that allows entering an absolute position in pixels.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: RadialGradient(
                colors: [Colors.white, Colors.blueAccent],
                center: Alignment(0,-0.5), // I want to input absolute position in pixels here!
              )
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do here is not to specify a pixel in the gradient part. You can place it using the position in your container and place a gradient for that area.